# Adding a character to the last column of a CSV in Python

Tags: python, linux

How to add Y in the last column of the CSV file by a python script? For example, I have CSV files as

```
fx, 00x, 2311, NI,
```

so how to write a direct script to add it automatically everytime I run that script by giving that particular file name?

Comment: This would be easier to do in a text editor, or with `sed`.  Are you going to be getting new files on a regular basis?

Comment: yes on regular basis and need to automate it with the script

Comment: What have you already written?  This is not a hard task.  `for line in open('my.csv'):` / `print( line + "Y\n")` will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

- The module needs to accept and use command line arguments.

  - One for the file path.
  - Another for the value to add to the last column.
- Open the file and iterate over it.
- Save each line/row as a list or other suitable container.

  - Append the new value to that container.
- Save all those containers in another list (container).
- Open the file for writing and write all those lines to it.

Comment: can you please help with the script

Comment: @chinu_globetrotter - ahh well from the way you asked your question I thought you were looking for a generalized algorithm.  `please help with the script` - Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.